# Unable to find xdmp:plan result documentation

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am having a hard time finding details about what the output of `xdmp:plan` means.

Having a simple query like this:

```
xdmp:plan(cts:search(doc(), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("description"), "some text")))
```

results in quite a long execution plan:

```
<qry:query-plan xmlns:qry="http://marklogic.com/cts/query">
<qry:expr-trace>...</qry:expr-trace>
...
<qry:partial-plan>
  <qry:term-query weight="1">
      <qry:key>16037778974159125508</qry:key>
      <qry:annotation>element(description,value("some","text"))</qry:annotation>
  </qry:term-query>
</qry:partial-plan>
...
<qry:ordering></qry:ordering>
<qry:final-plan>
  <qry:and-query>
    <qry:term-query weight="1">
      <qry:key>16037778974159125508</qry:key>
      <qry:annotation>element(description,value("some","text"))</qry:annotation>
    </qry:term-query>
  </qry:and-query>
</qry:final-plan>
<qry:info-trace>Selected 0 fragments to filter</qry:info-trace>
<qry:result estimate="0"></qry:result>
</qry:query-plan>
```

The only part of the documentation mentioning `xdmp:plan` is its [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:plan) itself. Other than that i can not find anything else. I'd like some details about what e.g. `qry:key` or `qry:annotation` really mean.

Is there any documentation i am missing describing the possible output of `xdmp:plan`. As this is a really valuable tool in order to understand query performance, i expected it to be rather well documented.

---

Edit: This [marklogic blog post](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/working-with-xdmp-plan/) i found gives some examples of how a query plan can be interpreted.

Still, i feel like a blog post should **not** be the **only reasonable documentation** for this tool.

Some questions still on my mind:

- Whats the difference between a `partial-plan` and a `final-plan`. Is a `final-plan` a merge of all `partial-plans`? For what and when is a `partial-plan` used? Partial-plans seem to contribute constraints. Are these constraints used at index resolution stage to find candidate fragment ids? What role does a `final-plan` play there? Is a `final-plan` used to filter out false-positives after the index resolution ?

Sometimes i can find this in the query plan:

```
<qry:elem-word-trace text="computer" elem-name="title" elem-uri="">
   <qry:key>10975994818398622042</qry:key>
</qry:elem-word-trace>
```

- What does a `qry:elem-word-trace` mean?
- What about `<qry:ordering></qry:ordering>`?
  Added a simple description about ordering to my answer.
- A simple xpath query like `/doc[id = 1]` outputs the following **2** times:

Is there a reason for that ? Why does step 2 predicate 1 contribute the same `partial-plan` twice?

```
<qry:info-trace>Step 2 predicate 1 contributed 1 constraint: id = 1</qry:info-trace>
<qry:partial-plan xmlns:qry="...">...</qry:partial-plan>
<qry:info-trace>Step 2 predicate 1 contributed 1 constraint: id = 1</qry:info-trace>
<qry:partial-plan xmlns:qry="...">...</qry:partial-plan>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more searching and reading i decided to summarize my findings.

**Note**: If you are not using fragmentation, every use of "fragment" can be put on par with "document".

## Partial vs Full-Plan

A `partial-plan` just shows the incremental pieces of the plan as the come in and seem to mostly be just for informational use.

The `full-plan` on the other hand is the request how it is sent to the index and thus most of the time the interesting part.

## Selected x fragments

The [documentation of query-trace](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/query_meters#id_77299) gives some insight of what the `info-trace` messages mean:

Having a **filtered** query results in a `info-trace` describing how many candidate fragments references were returned from the index resolution stage of query processing:

```
xdmp:plan(cts:search(doc(), cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("title"), "computer")))
=> ...
<qry:info-trace>Selected 2 fragments to filter</qry:info-trace>
```

A **unfiltered** query logs the same message but without the "to filter" indicating that the second filtering step is not executed:

```
xdmp:plan(cts:search(doc(), cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("title"), "computer"), ("unfiltered")))
=> ...
<qry:info-trace>Selected 2 fragments</qry:info-trace>
```

---

## qry:result

```
<qry:result estimate="2"></qry:result>
```

The `estimate` in `qry:result` shows how many fragments match the query using the index information alone. So this is a estimated number before the filtering step, thus might contain false-positives. I think the value of estimate and the log of info-trace described above is always the same.

---

## different annotation examples

Having a `element-word-query` with the only `word searches` enabled (`fast element word searches` disabled) returns this `final-plan`:

```
xdmp:plan(cts:search(doc(), cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("title"), "computer")))
=> ...
<qry:final-plan>
   <qry:and-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="1">
         <qry:key>13967911917401594192</qry:key>
         <qry:annotation>word("computer")</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="0">
         <qry:key>745773915438417736</qry:key>
         <qry:annotation>element(title)</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
   </qry:and-query>
</qry:final-plan>
```

Having two separate term-queries with one `word("computer")` and one `element(title)` means it will also return documents containing the word "computer" outside of element `title`. So a unfiltered search could return false-positives.

Having a `element-word-query` with **both** `word searches` **and** `fast element word searches` enabled returns this `final-plan`:

```
<qry:final-plan>
   <qry:and-query>
      <qry:term-query weight="1">
         <qry:key>10975994818398622042</qry:key>
         <qry:annotation>element(title,word("computer"))</qry:annotation>
      </qry:term-query>
   </qry:and-query>
</qry:final-plan>
```

Here `annotation` indicates a combined search for word "computer" inside the `title` element. This query could be unfiltered and still return no false-positives in my case.

More detailed information in this [blog post](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/working-with-xdmp-plan/).

---

## qry:ordering

That `<qry:ordering>` tag indicates that the resulting candidate fragment references are getting ordered. This can be controlled with one of the [cts:order Constructors](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts/cts:order-constructors) in the [cts:search](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search) function. Example:

```
xdmp:plan(
  cts:search(
    doc(), 
    cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("title"), "computer"), 
    (cts:unordered())
))
=>....
<qry:ordering>
    <qry:unordered></qry:unordered>
</qry:ordering>
```

---

## How to see, if a index is used

I always wondered, how to see if a index is used or not (being used to query execution plans where you have like a full index scan).
Ultimately you can tell quite easy if a index is used or not:

Search for `<qry:info-trace>` logs, which contain `searchable`. Messages which contain `searchable` are good, meaning this part of your query can be executed using a index. If it contains the word `unsearchable`, this might be a bad sign.

The log message for `xdmp:plan(//image/id[. = "1"]/..)` could look like this:

```
<qry:info-trace>Analyzing path: fn:collection()/descendant::image/id[. = "1"]/..</qry:info-trace>
<qry:info-trace>Step 1 is searchable: fn:collection()</qry:info-trace>
<qry:info-trace>Step 2 is searchable: descendant::image</qry:info-trace>
<qry:info-trace>Step 3 is searchable: id[. = "1"]</qry:info-trace>
<qry:info-trace>Step 4 axis is unsearchable: parent</qry:info-trace>
<qry:info-trace>Step 4 is unsearchable: ..</qry:info-trace>
```

Meaning all parts except Step 4, the `/..` can be resolved by the index. This might not be a bad sign, depending on your query. In this case, the query could be modified though:

This slightly modified query can use the index for all "steps" `xdmp:plan(//image[id = "1"]);`

```
<qry:info-trace>Analyzing path: fn:collection()/descendant::image[id = "1"]</qry:info-trace>
<qry:info-trace>Step 1 is searchable: fn:collection()</qry:info-trace>
<qry:info-trace>Step 2 is searchable: descendant::image[id = "1"]</qry:info-trace>
<qry:info-trace>Path is fully searchable.</qry:info-trace>
```

Further details can be found [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/query_meters#id_27932).

---

If someone finds more information on how to interpret and work with `xmdp:plan` output i'd be happy to know about it.

**Update 17.11.2018:**

Found this really interesting [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wV4Ns4-Kzw) where Mary Holstege talks about MarkLogic Search and Indexes. This covers a whole lot of my questions and i can really recommend it.

Comment: Also a interesting read, mholstege's answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53960795/3523756

Answer (score 1):

I would also add, if you see a term in the final plan with no annotation, that is a bug, and you should report it.